# slow download speed with rendered html

Tags: html, gzip, owin, self-hosting, razorengine

My page request content data after html loaded, it take 2 second for completed show page.

When i set all data in one html(server side rendering) and size 485KB, 
it take 4 second to show the page.

Why a 485KB size html load time slow than a 1.6MB json?

My server:
a self-host console server.
Owin & RazorEngine for html pages,
WebAPI for json data.

My 2 web page:
1. 
html, just static file,
use ajax(WebAPI) request json data.
[image: request 2 times,html and page data]

2.
Set all data in html, server side rendering.
[image: set data all in one]

--07/27 18:21 edit
*old title: Why small index html slow than a big json

I do some more test:
*All contents finally are all same.
1. html + webapi request content.
2. html + render content at server.
3. html with content,render nothing.
4. use webapi get html with content no gzip.
5. just for compare, stackoverflow has more waiting time, less download time.This is what i want.

[image: content download speed test]

Looks like the problem is RazorEngine.
Rendered html download speed slower than static file.
How do i fix this?

--07/28 10:38 edit

Just find out what problem is.
It's not RazorEngine's problem,the problem is gzip.
Some big html(977KB) use gzip(69KB) download speed faster(1.95s) than raw html(7.80s),
but sometimes gziped html download speed slower than raw html (third img).
[image: raw html slower than gziped html]

I set file size over 100kb to use gzip, but download speed still not stable.
Is there other problem i not found?

Comment: what about caching, ie rendered pages are hardly cached where as static files are usually by default. have you ensure its not cached. when measuring times

Answer (score 0):

Because when HTML is loaded, it also needs time for rendering on the browser depending upon the content. Thus, the time taken is more.

Comment: thanks for fast reply:) I don't think browser depending is the problem. The 2 page content data finally is the same.

Comment: Did it answer your question or you have any doubts?